# Callback for incoming call in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have a use case where I am trying to get all the details of incoming call in MS Teams e.g User who is calling, and I need to do some operations on backend when the call arrives. I was looking for something that would provide me callback when call comes with all the details to my custom service.

I researched a lot on this. Can this be achieved using some Microsoft SDK or Webhooks.

Comment: You need to use the botframework API's - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=json#team-members-added

Comment: @Gautam This will give me details once I receive the call right ? Is there anything I can get for the incoming call ?

Comment: This API is botframework API which is called everytime your bot is added to a team. It is also called whenever a user communicates with your bot. Please check the above url for all the various different events.

Comment: Sorry,If there is some problem in conveying, but my use case is not about adding a bot to team.I want to just get the incoming call details to mu service and not add any kind of bot.

Comment: i have been looking for a way for a long time too, without using a BOT.  just want an event to hook if Teams client rings, similar to what S4B COM API had.  Still doesn't look like MS have published a solution as of this date. would LOVE someone to prove me wrong....

Comment: @Vipulw Could you please try using the [Get call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api and see if this helps you?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT This requires call id. Is this available in teams sdk when the call arrives ? Also, I will receive call in teams via PBX.

Comment: @Vipulw Here are two ways to get the id of a callRecord:
1. Subscribe to [change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) to the /communications/callRecords endpoint.
2. Use the callChainId property of a call. The call record is available only after the associated call is completed.